# Upgraded project to Visual Studio 2010, but now get MVC error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc 1.0 project.  I upgraded the project and solution to Visual Studio 2010.  However, I do not want to use asp.net mvc 2.0.  My app compiles under mvc 1.0.  All my references are to 1.0.  I have copy local true and i am referencing mvc 1.0 from a lib folder, not the GAC.

However I keep getting this error:

```
 No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType) +82

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while creating a controller of type 'PartingOut.Web.Controllers.HomeController'. If the controller doesn't have a controller factory, ensure that it has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType) +189
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Its like it wants to keep using asp.net mvc 2.0, because its complaining about that GetControllerInstance method.

This project works fine in vs 2008.  wahhh!  :(

Anyone?  Anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How's your `HomeController` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Nothing to do with asp.net mvc 2 or vs 2010.  It was still referencing asp.net mvc 1.0 fine.  One of the other developers had done the upgrade and took out the "overrides" keyword in the method:

IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)

on our own custom ControllerFactory.

Meh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just trying to cover all the bases here, so forgive me if this is an obvious answer, but: Does `PartingOut.Web.Controllers.HomeController` actually have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: No it doesn't.  But it shouldn't.  I'm using StructureMap with DI so it has dependencies that get injected in to it.  The HomeController should always have its dependencies passed to it thru the constructor.

Comment: The error message says that `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory` is trying to instantiate your controller, not StructureMap. I haven't used StructureMap with MVC before, but shouldn't it be the one instantiating the controller, instead?

Comment: yeah i cant figure it out.  I have a custom ControllerFactory that uses structure map and I have that set in the global.asax.cs and it is running that line of code.  yet i still get the error that references the defaultcontrollerfactory.